# Image is displaying some garbled values

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts

I am using html,ajax and struts 2 to show image on UI. I am returning response as a byte[] of image from action and when I attach it with the image source then it shows some garbled values.

ajax call I am making from script is

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url:url,  
    contentType: "image/png",  
    success: function(data){  
        $('.logo').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />');  
    }
} );
```

and action from where I am returning array of image byte is like this

```
public void execute(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {  
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();  
    response.setContentType(action.getCustomContentType());
    response.getOutputStream().write(action.getCustomImageInBytes());
}

public byte[] getCustomImageInBytes() { 
    System.out.println("imageId" + imageId); 
    BufferedImage originalImage;
    try {
      originalImage = ImageIO.read(getImageFile("C:\\temp\\Desert.jpg"));
      // convert BufferedImage to byte array
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ImageIO.write(originalImage, "png", baos);
      baos.flush();
      imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
      baos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return imageInByte;
  }
```

Comment: Should you not be encoding as base64 anywhere or does write() on outstream do that for free??

Comment: is it necessary on the java side to encode into base64 because i am handling it on the script side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recreated your problem. It does appear to be the base64 encoding, although it works fine in the eclipse local preview without.

Use these two lines instead of response.getOutpuStream().write(...)

```
String encoded = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
                .printBase64Binary(action.getCustomImageInBytes());
response.getOutputStream().print(encoded);
```

My full solution:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic image test - stackoverflow issue 13946908</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url : "/Test/ImageServer",
      contentType : "image/png",
      success : function(data) {
        $('.logo').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<body>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```
public class ImageServer extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        byte[] data = getCustomImageInBytes(request.getServletContext()
                .getResource("/horse.jpg"));
        String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data);
        response.getOutputStream().print(encoded);
    }

    private byte[] getCustomImageInBytes(URL url) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(url);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        return imageInByte;
    }
}
```

Tested

- Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 OSX 10.7.5
- Firefox 16.0.2 OSX 10.7.5
- Safari 6.0.2 OSX 10.7.5

Comment: Thanks Adam your solution works for me. If I want to show image other than png like (jpeg and other format) then do I need to make changes and if so then where do I need to do necessary changes?
Cheers

Comment: yeah sure Andrea but my one part of the question is still unanswered.
Thanks

Comment: @ankit I'm not sure you need to make any changes. Your code will read any image format and render to the byte array in PNG format, which is what your Javascript code expects...

Comment: Thanks Adam. Just to inform you that other image formats are also rendering on the UI which proves your saying too. Cheers